# SimpleXML addChild issue when header sent

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this code :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<myxml></myxml>');
$xml->addChild('testNode attr="test Attribute"');
$node = $xml->addChild('erroNode attr="My Child node causes error -> expect >"');
//$node->addChild('nodeChild attr="node Child"');
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
exit();
```

I can create a childnode with attributes via `$xml`, but not with `$node`(child's child), Why? i get the error `error on line 2 at column 66: expected '>'` 
From the docs it say that the addChild function returns a SimpleXmlElement of the child. 
Check by uncommenting the commented line `$node->addChild('nodeChild attr="node Child"');`
Also it only happens when header is sent, if i comment header and do like below i can see the correct xml in page source :

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<myxml></myxml>');
    $xml->addChild('testNode attr="test Attribute"');
    $node = $xml->addChild('erroNode attr="My Child node causes error -> expect >"');
    $node->addChild('nodeChild attr="node Child"');
    //header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo $xml->asXML();
    exit();
```

My PHP version is 5.4.9

Comment: Seems to be working on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/, what is the error description ?

Comment: what is error. this code i tested works perfect with me

Comment: Perhaps your error is in `My Child node causes error -> expect >`, `>` is a reserved character in XML, this could cause trouble. Testing it right now...

Comment: Also attributes should be added with `addAttribute()`.

Comment: @JTeisseire, What do you mean `$node` does not exist? It is declared the line above... He is asking for **child's child**, not child.

Comment: Try uncommenting the code `$node->addChild('nodeChild attr="node Child"');`

Comment: I did. Works fine. What is your error message, please?

Comment: The error shows only when header is sent...

Comment: Could you try with your attributes set with `addAttribute()`? (what you are doin is wrong)

Comment: addAttribute works fine. But my question is if the previous node can be created that way then why cant its child?

Comment: I think because you use `attr="My Child node causes error -> expect >"` where it doesn't belong. Try your code without the wrong attribute setting. Thus no `attr="test Attribute"`, no `attr="My Child node causes error -> expect >"`, etc.

Comment: Weirdly, this is exactly the same mistake as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21378794/157957), apparently raised the same day by a different user!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is not coming from SimpleXML, but from your browser - that's why changing the HTTP header works. With this line, the browser knows the page is XML, and checks that it's valid; without it, it assumes it's HTML, and is more lenient:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

If you use "View Source" in your browser, you'll find that the actual output from PHP is the same in both cases. Another nice test is to set the content-type to `text/plain` instead, which means the browser won't interpret the output at all, just show it as-is.

So, for some reason, SimpleXML is generating invalid XML. This is because [the `->addChild()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) takes as its first argument just the **name** of the element to add, in your case `'erroNode'`; you are passing in an invalid name that also includes attributes, which should be added later with [`->addAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php).

---

If we simplify the example a bit further, and look at the XML generated, we can see what's going on (here's [an online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3V8QLv)):

```
// Make browser show plain output
header('Content-type: text/plain');

// Working example
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<myxml></myxml>');
$xml->addChild('testNode attr="test Attribute"');
echo $xml->asXML();

echo "\n";

// Broken example
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<myxml></myxml>');
$node = $xml->addChild('testNode attr="test Attribute"');
$node->addChild('test');
echo $xml->asXML();Child('testNode attr="test Attribute"');
$node->addChild('test');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

This outputs the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myxml><testNode attr="test Attribute"/></myxml>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myxml><testNode attr="test Attribute"><test/></testNode attr="test Attribute"></myxml>
```

The first version of the XML *appears* to be doing the right thing, because it has created a "self-closing tag". However, in the second, you can see that SimpleXML thinks that the tag name is `'testNode attr="test Attribute"'`, not just `'testNode'`, because that's what we told it.

The result is that it tries to put a closing tag with that "name", and ends up with `</testNode attr="test Attribute">`, which isn't valid XML.

Arguably, SimpleXML should protect you against this kind of thing, but now that you know, you can easily fix the code ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Mr4mRp)):

```
// Make browser show plain output
header('Content-type: text/plain');

// Fixed example
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<myxml></myxml>');
$node = $xml->addChild('testNode');
$node->addAttribute('attr', 'test Attribute');
$node->addChild('test');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Now, SimpleXML knows that the tag is just called `'testNode'`, so can create the correct closing tag when it needs to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myxml><testNode attr="test Attribute"><test/></testNode></myxml>
```